How to install python to run with Cygwin in MobaXterm in Windows machine?
I have installed python in Windows and accessed python in Mobaxterm.
As seen below, the compiler is MSC on Win32.

Howerver, I want to use python in Mobaxterm in Windows machine with GCC compiler on Cygwin.
How can I achieve that? Please see below for reference.

I need the python to use GCC compiler on cygwin, in my mobaxterm in the windows machine.
This way I can use sshpass in the python script.

Try to upgrade to a supported version of Python for both windows and cygwin. Cygwin is removing Python version 2 which has been unsupported for several years. The current Python version on Windows is 3.12, and on cygwin it is 3.9. The cygwin version is compiled with GCC.
